# ON/OFF flip button in Swing

Tags: java, swing, button

I wish to create a button exactly same as [this (from iOS5)](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/).

Comment: see this you may get some idea http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swing, there is `JToggleButton` which can have two status. However, if you want the button of the same shape and the same visual effect, you should implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You will have two images, for **ON** and for **OFF**.

Whenever you click the button, you will switch images with `button.setImage(..)`.

Swing constraints:

Button will still be rectangular, even though the image is oval

Animation possible, but quite hard AFAIK. From the way you asked your question, I think it will take you a while to study swing more